# Launching UITesting from command line

Tags: xcode7, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

As we know Apple introduced UITesting with Xcode 7. I have added the XCTestCase in my app and can rub the test via Xcode.

Is there any way i could run the test through terminal? eventually i would like my build server to run the tests for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this:

```
xcodebuild test -project path/to/<project name>.xcodeproj/ -scheme <scheme> -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES
```

Adjust accordingly.

I tried xctool, but ui tests didn't work, so I switched to xcodebuild

Comment: yes it doesn't run the UITesting, i would like it to open the simulator and run the UITests from command line.

Comment: Mine opens the simulator and runs the unit tests and ui tests.  Do you have both test targets (unit tests and ui tests) in the "Test" configuration of the scheme that you are using?

Comment: Mine doesn't open simulator. Just runs in shadow mode. 